# Ticking seconds with custom setInterval hook

Tags: reactjs, datetime, react-hooks

I'm trying to get an example of a ticking clock working with React Hooks and the [custom hook Dan created](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/). I'm banging my head trying to figure out what's wrong.

The following works:

```
function Clock() {

  const [currentDate, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  // useInterval(() => {
  //   setDate(currentDate.getSeconds() + 1);
  // }, 1000);

  return (
    <h1>{currentDate.toLocaleTimeString()}</h1>
  );
}
```

When I uncomment the `useInterval(...)` I get:

> TypeError: currentDate.toLocaleTimeString is not a function

If I then remove the `toLocalTimeString` I get:

> Objects are not valid as a React child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially your state is a `Date` object, but subsequently you're turning it into an integer.

Try this:

```
useInterval(() => {
   setDate(new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 1000));
}, 1000);
```

---

If you'd like to try TypeScript sometime, it's great for preventing/catching exactly this sort of errors. On your original code (posted in the question), TypeScript would have warned:

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.

[image: TypeScript catching the error]

And TypeScript is now supported in CRA:

> `create-react-app myapp --typescript`

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that! But you are correct. (Also, nice catch with respect to milliseconds value.

Comment: By the way, if you would like to try TypeScript sometime, it's great for catching exactly this sort of errors. `create-react-app my-app --typescript`

Comment: I am actually using TS but for some reason I couldn't decipher the error correctly — specifically, with the `useInterval` hook.

Comment: Got it; also side-note, generally don't rely on timers (setInterval, setTimeout) for accuracy. If you run the above code for long enough, you'll see that your state value will diverge (lag) from the actual datetime. Reason being that your callback function won't be called in exactly 1000ms intervals. If you're trying to show a clock (as the function name implies), the approach from @zhuber's answer is better. `useInterval(() => { setDate(new Date()) }, 1000)`

Comment: So I'm a little confused since I was basing my approach on [Dan Abramov's example](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/). I would have expected he would know the best approach.

Comment: @skube Right, I was similarly confounded. If you read Dan's blog post in full, you see that it's discussing a somewhat advanced (and confusing) situation where hooks are "declarative functions" and can lead to a problem known as "stale closures". Suggest reading Dan's post in full, and also Google "React Hooks Stale Closure" for some additional context and discussions.

Comment: @skube https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/

Answer (score 1):

You can just get current date every second

```
function Clock() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());

  setInterval(() => {
    setDate(new Date());
  }, 1000)

  return (
    <div>
      {date.toLocaleTimeString()}
    </div>
  );
}
```